# Difference between JBOSSAS and Netty

Tags: architecture, jboss, netty

Maybe this is a too newbie question, but I don't really understand the differente bs JSBOSS Application Server (now named WildFly) and Netty (or JBOSS Netty).

Are they both web servers? Are they frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildfly is a Java Enterprise Edition Server, meaning it implements the [Java EE specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition).

When you use Wildfly the jars provided by JBOSS should include implementations of all of the APIs listed in the specification above, i.e. javax.servlet for servicing HTTP requests, or javax.persistence (provided by Hibernate under the covers) for saving data to a database.

Netty is not a Java EE Server, it is a bare-bones framework for servicing any type of network request. It does not offer implementations of any of the API's listed in the Java EE Spec.

Netty provides different 'codecs' to service different types of common network requests like Http, SPDY, etc. Equally, if you have a custom network protocol you can write your own codec to handle it.

Netty does not, for example, offer any support for helping you write records to a database.

There are many other technical differences. Netty is effectively event-looped rather than thread-per-request, but the above is the key difference you're probably looking for.

Comment: this is closer to what I was expecting. Although I now understand it better it is not totally clear were is one in respect to the other. Are they in different layers or does Wildfly have _some_ layers in common with Netty?

Comment: let's see if I understood it right: in JBOSS I should place java code that need help interacting with the JEE specification (this includes some networking tasks), while in Netty I should place java code that need help only with networking tasks (but resolves other issues like persistance in their own). Is that a correct statement?

Comment: Basically correct. Java EE is a collection of API specifications commonly thought to be useful to people building 'Enterprise' applications. Receiving requests, doing stuff, logging results, communication via common protocols, writing things to databases. If you're writing an application and you don't want to re-invent the wheel, you should use EE apis. If you're very concerned about performance, being stream-lined, only using the absolute minimum possible and being 'close-to-the-iron' AND want to communicate over the network, use Netty.

Answer (score 1):

Wildfly is a full blown application server and Netty is "just" a network framework. So those are completely different in all means.

Comment: I see, but what are some features making them different? I don't understand the "blown application server" definition. Being Netty a network framework means an HTTP server only?